# Does Google index the Query URL formed during custom search made by user on site?

Tags: google-analytics, search-engine, google-search-console

A user starts off on  `www.example.com/article/1`

After searching on the site the URL becomes

`http://www.example.com/article/1?type=market&time=date`

This URL was made by the user based on selected filters

So does google itself generate such URL or does any kind of request needs to be sent to Google ?

For eg **Analytics request to google OR
       Google + button on the site**

which helps google to index such URL?

Answer (score 1):

If there are links that point to those URLs, then yes, they will be indexed.

`<a href="/article/1?type=market&time=date">market date</a>`

But, in Google Webmaster Tools there is a setting where you can tell Google which URL parameters are for sorting, and which display new content. My guess is so that they don't waste your crawling time on those repeat pages. (they would rather see new products than the same products but in reverse order).

Google Analytics will only pick it up if these two things happen:

1. someone visits that page
2. GA sends a `_trackPageview`.

The second point might not always be the case, for example, if you use `history.pushState`.